# Changing the namespace of a view generates an error in g.i.cs file?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces

I had changed a namespace of a view after moving it to other folder in the project, 
Now I got an error in its *.g.i.cs file :

> The type or namespace name 'Login' does not exist in the namespace
>   'TabibAssist' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

in files: Login.g.cs and Login.g.i.cs

I tried to delete the reference to the old namespace from this file, but it always regenerated after compiling the project

Comment: Create a new file in the new folder. Copy the contents of the Login view (except for the namespace) to the new files and remove the old files.

Comment: *"changed a namespace"* - you have to change it in two places: in xaml and in cs-file of that control (right click xaml in solution explorer - "view code"). Once you do it correctly the auto-generated files (containing `InitializeComponents()` implementation) should refresh.

Comment: @Sinatr In particular, you should modify the `x:Class=<namespace>.Login` attribute on the root element. in _Login.xaml_.

Comment: I did modify it. the workaround was to delete the file, created new and pasted the old code.. it works